# services \ remote service

Tags: android

sorry for a newbie question..
but "Service" by it's defenision meaning the same as "Remote service" in Android?

and if not, what is the diffrence between them?

thanks,

moshik.

Comment: can you give a reference to where they use the term "Service"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Service` is an Android component. A local `Service` is one that is used in-process by other components of an application (e.g., one or more `Activities`). A remote `Service` is one that exposes an interface via AIDL and is therefore usable by other applications across process boundaries.

Comment: Other applications.. could you give small example where you`ll think about remote service.. thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you are looking for sample code implementing a remote service, try http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClient/ and http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteService/

Comment: wasnt talkin about sampel code.. just like a sample idea.. when will u think about using remote service.. but thanks anyway!

Comment: Remote services are not that widespread, from what I can tell. Mostly, they are for cases where your app wants to also have what amounts to a "library" for other apps to use.

Comment: " what amounts to a "library" for other apps to use "
that was little bit tricky..